# A statement in Siegel's paper on Riemann-Siegel Formula

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ho.history-overview, theta-functions

Siegel left the following comment in the last paragraph of his famous "Über Riemanns Nachlaß zur analytischen Zahlentheorie", Section 1:

> Das Integral $\Phi(u)$ ist ein Spezialfall des Integrales $$\Phi(\tau,u)=\int_{0\nwarrow 1}\frac{e^{\pi i\tau x^2+2\pi iux}}{e^{\pi i x}-e^{-\pi i x}}\,\mathrm{d}x,\cdots$$ Die Transformationstheorie der Thetafunktionen hat bereits Riemann in seinen Vorlesungen auf die Eigenschaften von $\Phi(\tau,u)$ gegründet.

Here the integral path is a line with slope $-1$ passing between $0$ and $1$.

**Question:** I am quite interested in Siegel's comment. I tried hard to find out what Siegel refers to, but with no success. What did Riemann do with this integral for the transformation theory of theta function?

Comment: See the ["démonstration"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Par_une_int.C3.A9grale_de_contour) of $\zeta(s) =\frac{e^{-i\pi s}\Gamma(1-s)}{2i\pi}\int_C \frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{u}-1}du$ (which was in Riemann's original paper on $\zeta(s)$). Here it is the same applied to the [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i \pi \tau n^2 + 2i \pi u n}$. Both integral representation provide the functional equation